# have this puzzling PHP 5 OOP query

Tags: php, oop

I'm reading this ebook, *Beginning PHP5 and Mysql: From Novice to Professional*, and in the OOP section, I'm trying out this sample code to reproduce the same results on my computer vs the book.

```
class Staff
{
var $name;
var $city;
protected $wage;
    function __get($propName)
    {
        echo "__get called!<br />";
        $vars = array("name","city");
        if (in_array($propName, $vars))
        {
        return $this->$propName;
        } else {
        return "No such variable!";
        }
    }
}
$employee = new Staff();
$employee->name = "Mario";
echo $employee->name."<br />";
echo $employee->age;
```

In the book - the results are shown as:

```
Mario
__get called!
No such variable!
```

But on my computer:

```
Mario
```

Only the first line.  The other two lines were "ignored".  Why is that?!?!

Is there some configuration setting on my php.ini that I need to modify to get this working?  Can someone please help to explain?

Comment: Is the last line supposed to be `echo $employee->wage;`?

Comment: Is this your book? http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-PHP-MySQL-Novice-Professional/dp/1893115518 It is 8 years old and apparently uses PHP4.

Comment: @joeframbach: My book and this amazon link has the same title concidentally.  My book's 2006 edition.  It's 6 years old.

Comment: @handsofaten: No.  I copied the code straight off from the book, just to test the true 'Object-Oriented'ness behind it.  So no typo there.

Comment: Try adding this at the beginning of the script: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 1):

`__get()` will only get called for *non-public* or *non-existant* properties. Now, there is a property called `name`, so your magic method won't get called. Change `var $name` into `private $name` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I found the answer. According to php docs

> All overloading methods must be defined as public.

so make the magic method public

```
public function __get() {}
```